# Dismissed both Imagepickercontroller and current modally presented view controller(Pop Up controller)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have a button in 1st ViewController(ViewControllerA) on button click I have presented another viewController(ViewControllerB)(for pop UP , modalPresentationStyle is overCurrentContext) in this view controller I have logic to pick an image. Everything is working fine but when I Picked Image it dismissing both viewController and ImagePickerController.how to solve this?

//Presentin PopUPViewController from 1st view controller
//ViewControllerA.swift

```
 let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VehicleDetailsViewController") as! VehicleDetailsViewController
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
   present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

//imagePickerControllerDelegate method

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
            self.vehiclePhoto.image = pickedImage
            self.vehiclePhoto.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
             dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: maybe you should write picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)?

Comment: Solved it worked , Thank You

Comment: how come even after I call picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil), self.presentedViewController still shows image picker controller?